# IntelliJ ScalaTest - Test framework quit unexpectedly

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, scalatest

I'm using IntelliJ Ultimate 2019.2 and my tests work fine using SBT from the command line but running them inside IntelliJ using the ScalaTest configuration with the SBT option ticked I get:

**Test framework quit unexpectedly**

and this in the console:

```
Testing started at 13:27 ...
initialize
[IJ][academy-residences] $
[IJ][academy-residences] $ show {file:/C:/Users/Oliver/Workspace/academy- residences/}root/test:testOptions
[info] * Argument(Some(TestFramework(org.specs2.runner.Specs2Framework, org.specs2.runner.SpecsFramework)),List(sequential, true, junitxml, console))
[info] * Argument(Some(TestFramework(com.novocode.junit.JUnitFramework)),List(--ignore-runners=org.specs2.runner.JUnitRunner))
[info] * Argument(Some(TestFramework(org.scalatest.tools.Framework, org.scalatest.tools.ScalaTestFramework)),List(-oDU))
[info] * Argument(Some(TestFramework(org.scalatest.tools.Framework, org.scalatest.tools.ScalaTestFramework)),List(-oDU))
[info] * Argument(Some(TestFramework(org.scalatest.tools.Framework, org.scalatest.tools.ScalaTestFramework)),List(-oDU))
[info] * Argument(Some(TestFramework(org.scalatest.tools.Framework, org.scalatest.tools.ScalaTestFramework)),List(-oDU))
[info] * Argument(Some(TestFramework(org.scalatest.tools.Framework, org.scalatest.tools.ScalaTestFramework)),List(-oDU))
[info] * Argument(Some(TestFramework(org.scalatest.tools.Framework, org.scalatest.tools.ScalaTestFramework)),List(-oDU))
[info] * Argument(Some(TestFramework(org.scalatest.tools.Framework, org.scalatest.tools.ScalaTestFramework)),List(-oDU))
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed 9 Sep 2019, 13:27:22
[IJ][academy-residences] $
[IJ][academy-residences] $ set testOptions.in(ProjectRef(uri("file:/C:/Users/Oliver/Workspace/academy-residences/"), "root")) in Test+=Tests.Argument(TestFrameworks.ScalaTest, "-oDU")
[info] Defining Test / testOptions
[info] The new value will be used by Test / test / testOptions, Test / testOnly / testOptions, Test / testQuick / testOptions
[info] Reapplying settings...
[info] Set current project to academy-residences (in build file:/C:/Users/Oliver/Workspace/academy-residences/)
[IJ][academy-residences] $
[IJ][academy-residences] $ show {file:/C:/Users/Oliver/Workspace/academy-residences/}root/test:parallelExecution
[info] false
[IJ][academy-residences] $
[IJ][academy-residences] $ set parallelExec
```

Is there a log file somewhere I can look into to find out what's happening?

---

### update

sample of idea.log looks like this:

```
2019-09-09 15:02:02,782 [7334124]   INFO - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving Project 'C:\Users\Oliver\Workspace\academy-residences' academy-residenceslibraryTable took 31 ms 
2019-09-09 15:02:02,831 [7334173]   INFO - mponents.impl.stores.StoreUtil - saveProjectsAndApp took 208 ms 
2019-09-09 15:02:21,726 [7353068]   WARN - j.openapi.wm.impl.IdeFrameImpl - Set preferredFocusableComponent in 'BookingDAO' content in Run tool window to avoid focus-related problems. 
2019-09-09 15:02:21,726 [7353068]   WARN - j.openapi.wm.impl.IdeFrameImpl - BookingDAO tool window - parent container is hidden 
2019-09-09 15:02:28,635 [7359977]   INFO - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving Project 'C:\Users\Oliver\Workspace\academy-residences' academy-residenceslibraryTable took 28 ms 
2019-09-09 15:02:28,719 [7360061]   INFO - ij.compiler.impl.CompileDriver - COMPILATION STARTED (BUILD PROCESS) 
2019-09-09 15:02:29,416 [7360758]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stdout]: Build process started. Classpath: C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2/plugins/java/lib/jps-launcher.jar 
2019-09-09 15:02:29,551 [7360893]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder". 
2019-09-09 15:02:29,551 [7360893]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation 
2019-09-09 15:02:29,552 [7360894]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details. 
2019-09-09 15:02:30,567 [7361909]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred 
2019-09-09 15:02:30,567 [7361909]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.google.protobuf.UnsafeUtil (file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202019.2/lib/protobuf-java-3.5.1.jar) to field java.nio.Buffer.address 
2019-09-09 15:02:30,567 [7361909]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.google.protobuf.UnsafeUtil 
2019-09-09 15:02:30,567 [7361909]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations 
2019-09-09 15:02:30,568 [7361910]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release 
2019-09-09 15:02:30,624 [7361966]   INFO - .ScalaCompilerReferenceService - [compiler indices] onCompilationStart. active indexing phases: 1 
2019-09-09 15:02:33,714 [7365056]   INFO - .ScalaCompilerReferenceService - [compiler indices] startIndexing. clean build: false 
2019-09-09 15:03:13,127 [7404469]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in opaque part at index 14: jrt:C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2/jbr 
2019-09-09 15:03:13,130 [7404472]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2915) 
2019-09-09 15:03:13,130 [7404472]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:3086) 
2019-09-09 15:03:13,130 [7404472]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3122) 
2019-09-09 15:03:13,130 [7404472]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: at java.base/java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:600) 
2019-09-09 15:03:13,130 [7404472]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: at java.base/java.net.URL.toURI(URL.java:1018) 
2019-09-09 15:03:13,131 [7404473]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: at com.intellij.compiler.instrumentation.InstrumentationClassFinder$ClassFinderClasspath.getLoader(InstrumentationClassFinder.java:539) 
2019-09-09 15:03:13,131 [7404473]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: at com.intellij.compiler.instrumentation.InstrumentationClassFinder$ClassFinderClasspath.getLoader(InstrumentationClassFinder.java:520) 
2019-09-09 15:03:13,131 [7404473]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: at com.intellij.compiler.instrumentation.InstrumentationClassFinder$ClassFinderClasspath.getResource(InstrumentationClassFinder.java:486) 
2019-09-09 15:03:13,131 [7404473]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: at com.intellij.compiler.instrumentation.InstrumentationClassFinder.getClassBytesStream(InstrumentationClassFinder.java:183) 
2019-09-09 15:03:13,131 [7404473]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: at com.intellij.compiler.instrumentation.InstrumentationClassFinder.loadClass(InstrumentationClassFinder.java:132) 
2019-09-09 15:03:13,132 [7404474]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: at com.intellij.compiler.instrumentation.InstrumenterClassWriter.getCommonSuperClass(InstrumenterClassWriter.java:27) 
2019-09-09 15:03:13,132 [7404474]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.SymbolTable.addMergedType(SymbolTable.java:1198) 
2019-09-09 15:03:13,132 [7404474]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.Frame.merge(Frame.java:1295) 
2019-09-09 15:03:13,132 [7404474]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.Frame.merge(Frame.java:1176) 
2019-09-09 15:03:13,133 [7404475]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.MethodWriter.computeAllFrames(MethodWriter.java:1617) 
2019-09-09 15:03:13,133 [7404475]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.MethodWriter.visitMaxs(MethodWriter.java:1553) 
2019-09-09 15:03:13,133 [7404475]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.MethodVisitor.visitMaxs(MethodVisitor.java:768) 
2019-09-09 15:03:13,133 [7404475]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.MethodVisitor.visitMaxs(MethodVisitor.java:768) 
2019-09-09 15:03:13,133 [7404475]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: at com.intellij.compiler.notNullVerification.NotNullVerifyingInstrumenter$2.visitMaxs(NotNullVerifyingInstrumenter.java:329) 
2019-09-09 15:03:13,133 [7404475]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readCode(ClassReader.java:2427) 
2019-09-09 15:03:13,134 [7404476]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readMethod(ClassReader.java:1276) 
2019-09-09 15:03:13,134 [7404476]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:680) 
2019-09-09 15:03:13,134 [7404476]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:392)
```

Can't see anything in there that looks suspicious except:

`SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".`

Comment: Please check idea.log and build.log ("Help | Show log in...") for errors/warnings.

Comment: Thanks @y.bedrov I found idea.log, just updated question with a sample of it after running the tests a few times

Comment: Those messages are harmless, but fixed for 2019.3 version: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-220285. Is it possible to share sample project example for investigation?

Comment: unfortunately not as this is for a client of mine and the repository is private. Can I share any more info with you that may help diagnose the issue?

Comment: Isn't it reproducible with new sample proejct?